# why $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have $x=\cos t$ and want to evaluate $\cfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. I already calculated $\cfrac{dy}{dx}$ to find second derivative the book I am reading from, used this:

$$\cfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\cfrac{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$$

My question is how we obtained this formula?

Comment: Hint: Denote $z=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Further hint: use the chain rule.

Comment: Hmm. got it thank you.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But what is $y$ ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Original question didn't mentioned about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\cfrac{d}{dx}\left(\cfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=\cfrac{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cfrac{\cfrac{d}{dt}\left(\cfrac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx/dt}=\cfrac{dt}{dx}\left(\cfrac{d}{dt}\right)\left(\cfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=\cfrac{d}{dx}\left(\cfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=\cfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If we have $ \dfrac{u}{v} = c$ constant temporarily, then by chain rule we also have  $ \dfrac{u'}{v'} = c$ when differentiated w.r.t. $t$

$$\cfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d[dy/dx]}{dx}$$

From independent variable $x$ now we newly consider switching to  $t$ so that

$$\cfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\cfrac{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}.$$